# How do I set up my webpage to take input from a text field and use it as new text on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

I am trying to make a web app that works as flash cards but I need to be able to take what the user types into a textbook and add it to the page. Here is what I have found but I want the text to be embedded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title>textBoxes.html</title>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  // from textBoxes.html
  function sayHi(){
  var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
  var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
  var name = txtName.value;
  txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " + name + "!"
  } // end sayHi
 </script>
 <link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "textBoxes.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Text Box Input and Output</h1>
 <form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Type your name: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "txtName" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "txtOutput" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by embedded?? to make it part of a <p> or <a> tag rather a textfield? if so 'document.getElementById(id of tag). innerHTML = "Hi there, " + name + "!"' like its mentioned [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: If you're going to want to save these results, your best bet is to POST the text to a page that handles the request with PHP and saves it into a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). It can do what you want. And **so much more**!

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <input type "text" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="name" />

  <h3>Hello<span ng-show="name">, </span>{{name}}!</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You can also use JQuery: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9hednur/)

If you don't want to use Angular, this works:

```
  function writeToElement(id, value){
    var target= document.getElementById("id");
    if (target) {
        target.innerHTML = value;
        return target;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Then you can set an onClick to `writeToElement(someId, this.value)` where `someId` is the id of the element you want to change.